# How to get user's roles, Discord, Python

Tags: python, discord

I've been improving and improving my bot.
Now, I've figured out how to make the bot purge messages, but a purge message, shouldn't be allowed to any member, only to people with certain role.

I've done this code:

```
if author.roles.has("BotModerator"):
```

I've looked for it, on this website(https://anidiotsguide.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/information/understanding_roles.html), but seems that they're coding with Java, how can I do it in Python?

By the way, the error shown in the output is 'list' object has no atribute 'has'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The roles a `User` has is a list of `role` objects, you'll need to access the name property of the role. You can use list comprehension.

```
if "botmoderator" in [y.name.lower() for y in author.roles]:
```

But of course, this limits that command to only people with the specific role, BotModerators. It can't be used in another server unless they aswell have a role called BotModerator. I recommend you using the id instead. If you don't know how, tag the role then put a backslash in front of the name then send. Should show you the role's id. Then you can use that instead.

```
if "role_id" in [y.id for y in author.roles]:
```

Comment: It keeps saying that I don't have the role, when I do. ._.

Comment: Nevermind, I had forgot to save. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Um. Actually it only works if the role's name is set on the script to 'botmoderator', if I try something else, it says that I don't have the role, even when I do.

Comment: Also be sure you have the name of the role right including emojis if any. I recommend you use the id of the role instead @Norby

Comment: There's what happens, when I tried using a different name for the role: https://prnt.sc/frluhh | https://prnt.sc/frlu50

Comment: And btw, the Id thing is a great idea, I might get some people for help me when someone needs help, and using that, would allow them to. If I use the Id thing, I can't make like "local" admins, I mean, the owner of the server, can make people moderators/admins for use certain comments, like "purge", "kick".

Comment: Found the issue. I can't use capitals. ._.

Comment: Thats why inside the list comprehension I put `[y.name.lower()` so you don't worry about capitals, since it will make all the role name in lower case in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `author.roles` is a python `list`. You may be able to check for the presence of your "BotModerator" role like so:

```
if "BotModerator" in author.roles:
```

Haven't tried it myself, so can't verify currently.

Alternatively, if each role is an object, you may need something like:

```
role_names = [role.name for role in author.roles]
if "BotModerator" in role_names
```

If each role is a dict, try the same as above, but with either `role['name']` or `role.get('name')` instead of role.name.